# How to number matrices (histograms of images) with different sizes and retrieve them (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matrix, cbir

Using Matlab, I have 1000 color images, their histograms have the size either 384*256*3 or 256*384*3, so they are matrices.
I want to number them, and later retrieve them. I know I cannot do this:

```
for z=1:1000
H(:,:,:,z)={imread(strcat('image.orig/',int2str(z-1),'.jpg'))};
end
```

But my question is how can I number the 1000 matrices and later I can get any of them, like for the first image, simply using

```
H(:,:,:,1)
```

to get the matrix. I know their sizes are different so I cannot set

```
H=zeros(384,256,3,1000);
```

because that only work for the matrices of the size 384*256*3.

So what I should do to save the matrices and simply using a number from 1 to 1000 within a variable name to get any of the matrix?

It is just how can I number different matrices and get each of them later?

Hope I stated clear what's my problem. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Have you tried a `cell` array? `H{z} = imread(...)`.  Sizes can be different, data types different, etc.

Answer (score 2):

As chappjc said, it is better to store in a cell.

```
H=cell(1000,1);

for z=1:1000
    H{z}=imread(strcat('test',int2str(z),'.jpg'))
end
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  I edited your post for code formatting.  In the future, to make your code nicely formatted, I recommend you have a look here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks .  Have fun!